# How can I kill a 16bit process held by nvtdm.exe?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, 16-bit

I have a c# application that monitors wmi process start / terminate events.  I need to also detect an old legacy 16 bit application starting.  I am able to determine if my legacy app starts using code I found in this link - [16-Bit Apps running under NTVDM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649827/16-bit-apps-running-under-ntvdm)

But here's my question... Say I want to kill a 16bit  process that was started by ntvdm.exe, how would I do that?  I don't think I want to kill ntvdm.exe itself incase it is managing other 16bit process or whatever not related to my code.